# Can not "link"SimpleITK::Show() with FIJI

Tags: python, imagej, simpleitk, fiji

I am running on Ubuntu. When calling the Show method of SimpleITK I am not being able to view such image in my FIJI ( ImageJ2) window.

Given that FIJI is a portable application, is it necessary to perform some more process in order to properly link Show method with it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

SimpleITK requires an external image viewer to display images (ImageJ, 3DSlicer, ITK-Snap, etc).

**ImageJ Installation**

1. Go to https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/download.html
2. Make sure to download the `bundled with 64-bit Java 1.8.0_112` version

---

**ImageJ Setup**

1. Go to https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/plugins/nifti.html
2. Download `nifti_io.jar`
3. Go to `C:\blah\blah\ImageJ\plugins\Input-Output`
4. Delete the existing `nifti_io.jar` file from the folder
5. Copy the downloaded `nifti_io.jar` file into the folder
6. Restart ImageJ and check if `File -> Import -> NIfTI-Analyze` is there
7. If it is there, the plugin was successfully installed

---

**SimpleITK Setup**

1. Find the path where your `ImageJ.exe` file exists
2. Open `cmd`
3. Type in `setx SITK_SHOW_COMMAND "C:\blah\blah\ImageJ\ImageJ.exe"`
4. You should get the message `SUCCESS: Specified value was saved`

---

**Check if everything works**

1. Restart your text editor or IDE (if it was already open)
2. Run your code